# Mercurial: How can I see in advance what changes will an `hg up` do to my working directory?

Tags: mercurial

I'm regularly updating a production server which is running from an hg working directory.
I always update to a merged/resolved changeset after testing that changeset in the development server, but want an extra layer of safety to see, before updating, which changes will be made (a diff so to speak between the current state of the files and the tip).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run a diff vs. the tip like so:

```
hg diff -r tip
```